# How to place multiple textviews in Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

SearchAdapter.java

```
public class SearchFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public int layout;
    public class ViewHolder2 {
        TextView pf_businessTitle;
        TextView pf_addressDistance;
        TextView pf_businessAddress;
        TextView pf_businessLocation;
        TextView pf_businessState;
        TextView pf_businessZipCode;
    }

    // MyEvents myEvents;
    public SearchFeedAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        layout=resource;
    }
    Context mContext;



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){

        SearchFeedAdapter.ViewHolder2 mainViewHolder=null;
        mContext = parent.getContext();

        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView= inflater.inflate(layout,parent,false );

        final SearchFeedAdapter.ViewHolder2 viewHolder=new SearchFeedAdapter.ViewHolder2();
        viewHolder.pf_businessTitle =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessTitle);
        viewHolder.pf_addressDistance =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_addressDistance);
        viewHolder.pf_businessAddress=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessAddress);
        viewHolder.pf_businessLocation=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessLocation);
        viewHolder.pf_businessState=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessState);
        viewHolder.pf_businessZipCode=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessZipCode);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        viewHolder.pf_businessTitle.setText(getItem(position));

        mainViewHolder=(SearchFeedAdapter.ViewHolder2)convertView.getTag();
       //  mainViewHolder.pf_businessTitle.setText(getItem(position));
       // String distance;
       // mainViewHolder.pf_addressDistance.setText(getItem(position));
        return convertView;


    }

}
```

SearchActivity.java

```
public class SearchFeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

    public static ArrayList<String> BusinessTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> Distance = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> Address = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> Location=new ArrayList <String> ();
    public static ArrayList<String> State=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ZipCode=new ArrayList<String>();


    public static ArrayAdapter<String> pfAdapter1;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> pfAdapter2;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> pfAdapter3;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> pfAdapter4;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> pfAdapter5;
    public static ArrayAdapter<String> pfAdapter6;
    ListView show;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
        show= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_pf);
        pfAdapter1 = new SearchFeedAdapter(SearchFeedActivity.this, R.layout.searchfeed_adapter,BusinessTitle);
        showData(pfAdapter1);



    }
    public void showData(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        show.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

I want to place these textviews in two rows.I want to place that data in two different rows and keep updated.I am not concerned about this ArrayAdapter if you have any alternate please let me know the alternate to accomplish that task.

Comment: To host more complex views in a ListView, you need to create a custom adapter. The custom adapter will `extend` ArrayAdapter, but have added functionality for displaying the view exactly as you need. Here's a good tutorial: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Answer (score 0):

public class SubtopicCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
int count;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<SubTopicsModel> listState;
private SubtopicCustomAdapter myAdapter;
private boolean isFromView = false;



public SubtopicCustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<SubTopicsModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.listState = objects;
    this.myAdapter = this;
}




@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}




public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView,
                          ViewGroup parent) {

    listState.get(position).setExpert("0");
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.subtopic_spinner_adapter, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mTextView.setText(listState.get(position).getTopic_name());




    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;
}
```

}

You can create your custom adapter as per your own desire,All you need is to just create your layout and inflate it.

Answer (score 0):

First you swap the these 2 lines

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
show.setAdapter(adapter);
```

to

```
show.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And how many ListView`s do you have? 1 listview requires only 1 adapter. You have so many adapters.

If you want to show many data in adapter use CustomModel. Like this

```
public class MyModel {
public String title;
public String distance;
public String address;
public String location;
public String state;
public String zipCode;
```

}

And your AdapterClass

```
public class SearchFeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyModel> {

public int layout;
public class ViewHolder2 {
    TextView pf_businessTitle;
    TextView pf_addressDistance;
    TextView pf_businessAddress;
    TextView pf_businessLocation;
    TextView pf_businessState;
    TextView pf_businessZipCode;
}

// MyEvents myEvents;
public SearchFeedAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<MyModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    layout=resource;
}
Context mContext;



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){

    SearchFeedAdapter.ViewHolder2 mainViewHolder=null;
    mContext = parent.getContext();

    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_with_textviews,parent,false );

    final SearchFeedAdapter.ViewHolder2 viewHolder=new SearchFeedAdapter.ViewHolder2();
    viewHolder.pf_businessTitle =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessTitle);
    viewHolder.pf_addressDistance =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_addressDistance);
    viewHolder.pf_businessAddress=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessAddress);
    viewHolder.pf_businessLocation=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessLocation);
    viewHolder.pf_businessState=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessState);
    viewHolder.pf_businessZipCode=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pf_businessZipCode);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    viewHolder.pf_businessTitle.setText(getItem(position).title);
    viewHolder.pf_addressDistance.setText(getItem(position).distance);
    viewHolder.pf_businessAddress.setText(getItem(position).address);
    viewHolder.pf_businessLocation.setText(getItem(position).location);
    viewHolder.pf_businessState.setText(getItem(position).state);
    viewHolder.pf_businessZipCode.setText(getItem(position).zipCode);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

And your Activity Like this

```
public class SearchFeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

public static ArrayList<MyModel> myModels = new ArrayList<MyModel>();



public static ArrayAdapter<String> pfAdapter1;

ListView show;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
    show= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_pf);
    loadMyModels();
    pfAdapter1 = new SearchFeedAdapter(SearchFeedActivity.this, R.layout.searchfeed_adapter,myModels);
    showData(pfAdapter1);



}

private void loadMyModels() {

    //Load your data here. It`s dummy object creation
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.title = "title " + i;
        model.address = "address " + i;
        model.distance = "distance " + i;
        model.location = "location " + i;
        model.state = "state " + i;
        model.zipCode = "zipcode " + i;
        myModels.add(model);
    }
}
public void showData(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter){
    show.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

At the end use RecyclerView instead of ListView in future